# I am struggling with my algorithm to find the lowest values in a matrix C++

Tags: c++, matrix

In my program, I am trying to find the lowest values in the row of a matrix, then find the lowest value in the next row corresponding to the column it was found.

I wrote a function that does most of that work, however, I am confused on the algorithm:

Declare and define a function that computes the index where the lowest (non-zero) values are found in a given row.

It takes three parameters; the 2D array declared in the main function that is the matrix, the 1D array that contains the list of all rows that were visited and an integer that represents a row in the 2D array.

For each of the columns in a row, compute the lowest non-zero value only if that row wasn’t visited before.

I am lost on how to move to the next row of the column with the lowest value

`int const SIZE = 10;`

```
int lowest_level(int array_2D[][SIZE], int path[], int row /* current row*/)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        int minValue = array_2D[i][0];  // sets min value every row
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j)
        {
            if (path_checker(path, row) == false)    // if row was not 
                                                        visited
            {
                if ((array_2D[i][j] < minValue) && array_2D[i][j] != 0) // if 
                                       value is less than min & value is not 0
                {
                    minValue = array_2D[i][j];
                    //cout << minValue << " ";    // for testing; crashes

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //return (minValue);
}
```

I expect something like this

```
   A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
    -----------------------------------------------
A | 00   08   15   01   10   05   19   19   03   05   
B | 06   00   02   08   02   12   16   03   08   17   
C | 12   05   00   14   13   03   02   17   19   16   
D | 08   07   12   00   10   13   08   20   16   15   
E | 04   12   03   14   00   05   02   12   14   09   
F | 08   05   03   18   18   00   04   02   10   19   
G | 17   16   11   03   09   07   00   03   05   09   
H | 07   06   11   10   11   11   07   00   14   09   
I | 10   04   05   15   17   01   07   17   00   09   
J | 05   20   07   04   18   19   19   03   10   00

Path
A --> D --> B --> C --> G --> H --> J --> I --> F --> E (path by rows it takes)
1     7     2     2     3     9     10    1     18  (lowest values in each row, next value corresponding to the column (1 = coordinates (A, D))
```

Comment: You could determine the lowest value for each row storing it in a (local) `std::map` with pairs of (value, row index). `std::map` sorts entries automatically. Hence, just by iterating through the `std::map` will provide the order (I believe) you are looking for. The advantage: every matrix value has to be inspected once only. (Alternatively, you could use a `std::vector` and call `std::sort` with a custom predicate.)